# Call to undefined $class() in w3style blog article on PHP dynamic front controllers

Tags: php, oop

All,

I am reading the following article on a lightweight PHP dynamic front controller: http://www.w3style.co.uk/a-lightweight-and-flexible-front-controller-for-php-5

Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<?php

define("PAGE_DIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/pages");
require_once "FrontController.php";
FrontController::createInstance()->dispatch();
```

**FrontController.php**

```
<?php

class FrontController {
  public static function createInstance() {
    if (!defined("PAGE_DIR")) {
      exit("Critical error: Cannot proceed without PAGE_DIR.");
    }
    $instance = new self();
    return $instance;
  }
  public function dispatch() {
    $page = !empty($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : "home";
    $action = !empty($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "index";
    //e.g. HomeActions
    $class = ucfirst($page) . "Actions";
    //e.g. pages/home/HomeActions.php
    $file = PAGE_DIR . "/" . $page . "/" . $class . ".php";
    if (!is_file($file)) {
      exit("Page not found");
    }
    require_once $file;
    $actionMethod = "do" . ucfirst($action);  

    $controller = new $class(); // I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS DOES...  

    if (!method_exists($controller, $actionMethod)) {
      exit("Page not found");
    }
    //e.g. $controller->doIndex();
    $controller->$actionMethod();
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

**pages/guestbook/GuestbookActions.php**

```
<?php

class GuestbookActions {
  public function doIndex() {
    echo "Index action called...";
  }
  public function doCreatePost() {
    echo "CreatePost action called...";
  }
}
```

In the front controller class, could someone explain to me what `$controller = new $class();` does?  I don't understand it.  It seems to be creating a class on the fly?  In the example above, `$class` is a string with a value like `"HomeActions"`.  So `$controller` would be a new instance of a class named `"HomeActions"`, but those are not defined anywhere.  I'm confused.

Many thanks,

JDelage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$controller = new $class();
```

That does indeed create a new object of the type contained in `$class`, so it is equivalent to `$controller = new HomeActions()` in your example.  From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new):

> If a string containing the name of a class is used with *new*, a new instance of that class will be created

The classes are not all present initially.  However, the necessary one is loaded dynamically:

```
$file = PAGE_DIR . "/" . $page . "/" . $class . ".php";
if (!is_file($file)) {
  exit("Page not found");
}
require_once $file;
```

[`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) loads the file which presumably contains the class definition, so you can create the object as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The example request in the article is to http://localhost/index.php?page=guestbook&action=index, so `$class` would be GuestbookActions, which is defined in the third code sample.